# How can I change the access token in SignalR connection?

Tags: signalr, jwt, access-token

I want to create the web application (SPA with angular) with token based authentication.

It is required create the access token with short live-time, perhaps 1 hour expiration.

I want to use the SignalR for real-time communication and I have tried send the access token via query string after starting signalr connection.

If is access token expired I create the http request for refresh it and recieved it to the javascript.

How can I send the new access token if is signalr connection is running?

Is possible change the token or is necessary close the connection and create new again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the transport technology that is used. In case of websockets you have to stop the connection, set the query-string and restart the connection. With other technologies you can directly change the query-string. You can check `$.connection.hub.transport.name` to learn what transport method is being used.